# Too many actors in LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm programming my first game in LibGDX and part of the gameplay has a mixing logic between elements (similar to Doodle God or Little Alchemy). By reading and watching guides, I've attempted to design this logic using LibGDX classes `Stage`, `Actor` (for the elements) and `Group`(for organising elements), but then I realised I would need an actor for each element. Since I intend to have over 150 of them, creating a java class for each one really doesn't feel optimal. Neither do I know an efficient way to store all the logic so I can look for combinations with a single call (I don't want to write a million `if` statements in a method).

I would like to know if there's a simple and elegant way for doing that. Thanks in advance!

P.S.: The only differences between elements are their textures, the groups they go into and the elements they combine with.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a pattern that is currently well used for doing what you expect. It's called entity-component-system (or ECS).

It requires a shift in thinking how to develop games, but it's worth it, especially for its modularity and reusability.

Wikipedia has a much [detailed article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system).

And it's a good thing that libgdx has [Ashley](https://github.com/libgdx/ashley), their ECS implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, reuse Actors maybe?

If we talk about logic. 
You can group logics and write a function for every group.
Don't use ifs, use switch and enums.

Maybe if you tell us more then we can come with something innovative.